# Why Doesn't .attr Work but .getAttributes does?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out why `attr()` doesn't work but `getAttribute()` does. Can somebody please tell me why I'm facing this problem? Here is the code:

```
$('#assignAssetBtn').on('click', function () {
    tableTools = $('#Grid').DataTable();
    $.each(tableTools.$('td input', { 'filter' : 'applied' }), function (idx, data) {
        // $.each(tableTools.fnGetSelectedData(), function (idx, data) { // this was not working so I changed the code a little bit 
        if (this.checked == true) {
            debugger;
            assetList.push({ 
                'id': data.value, 
                'name': (data).getAttribute('name') 
            });
        }
    });
});

 $('#assignAssetBtn').on('click', function () {
        tableTools = $('#Grid').DataTable();
        $.each(tableTools.$('td input', { 'filter' : 'applied' }), function (idx, data) {
            // $.each(tableTools.fnGetSelectedData(), function (idx, data) { // this was not working so I changed the code a little bit 
            if (this.checked == true) {
                debugger;
                assetList.push({ 
                    'id': data.value, 
                    'name': $(data).attr('name') 
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I have tried it with $(data) but that doesn't works

Comment: You are missing `$` before `(data)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've tried this. That doesn't works.

Comment: can you put your code with attr syntax you tried ?

Comment: @Garden it should work fine, given your code sample. Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code

Comment: @JekinKalariya I have added the code

Comment: code seams to be fine, try to debug your data attribute value, is it properly have name attribute

Comment: yeah it does. This is the html `<input type="checkbox" class="Select" name="testing" value="1">`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the '$' alias in your code which is a reference to the jQuery function.
It works like so:

```
$(selector).action()
```

And since the 'attr()' function is jQuery, you'd need to reference it.

Try:

```
assetList.push({ 'id' : data.value, 'name' : $(data).attr('name') });
```

Comment: Adding the `$` doesn't helps

Comment: I would put a short explanation of what was incorrect, rather than just posting code. You might be right - but I think if you can explain what the issue was and how to resolve it, you would get a +1 vote

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
assetList.push({ 'id' : data.value, 'name' : $(data).attr('name') });
```

You have to use the dollar sign at the start to access jquery. You can find the jquery documentation over here:
[Jquery Syntax Documenatation](http://A%20$%20sign%20to%20define/access%20jQuery)